# If statement inside Do while loop not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am new at excel VBA and i am facing this problem, i am writing a code which supposed to see the value of a cell and then goes through a list of numbers and gets the **next higher or equal** number through this list.

The problem is that the code works fine and gets me the next higher number, but when it comes to the **equal** part it doesn't work, i wrote an if statement which breaks the loops when the condition of (equal) is achieved but it seems that this line is not executed.
Would please help me figure why is this happening

my code looks something like this

```
Do While ([c12] < [h13])
If ([c12] = [h13]) Then
    Exit Do
End If
[c12].Value = Worksheets("lists").Cells(cb, 9)
cb = cb + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Are the numbers integers ? give an example of the two numbers that are not matching.

Answer (score 0):

When your `If` statement would be True your `While` will always be False so the loop ends before that `If` ever triggers.

If you were to change the `While` to a `Do` you can see the `If` statement executing.

```
    Do
        If ([c12] = [h13]) Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        [c12].Value = Worksheets("lists").Cells(cb, 9)
        cb = cb + 1
    Loop
```

Comment: Sadly same problem occurs. 
The value that i am looking for is 80, and this number exists a the list that i am looping through, thus the loop should stop at 80. But is gives me 100 which is the next value.

Comment: A rounding issue then most likely or possibly one is actually a string while the other is a number.

Answer (score 0):

I think I agree with @Warcupine that the "If" is unnecessary.

How about building your "If" condition just into the conditional loop itself?

```
Do
   [c12].Value = Worksheets("lists").Cells(cb, 9)
   cb = cb + 1
Loop Until ([c12] >= [h13])
```

Answer (score 0):

### First Numeric Value Greater Than...

- Adjust `I2` (the first row 2) and `Sheet1` (tab name).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Lists")
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Range("I" & sws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("I2:I" & slRow) ' adjust "I2"

    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' adjust "Sheet1"
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range("C12")
    Dim dValue As Variant: dValue = dws.Range("H13").Value
    If Not IsNumeric(dValue) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim sValue As Variant
    
    ' Loop and write.
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        sValue = sCell.Value
        If IsNumeric(sValue) Then
            If sValue >= dValue Then ' value found...
                dCell.Value = sValue
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next sCell
    ' value not found...
    dCell.Value = "" ' or '0', or remove to keep as-is
 
End Sub
```